# Password not being saved to database using Knex and Argon2

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to seed my database with a couple of sample users. I am using Knex for my postgres database and npm-argon2 for password hashing. As far as I can tell, my simple hasing function works, but when I run it at insertion time, it saves an empty object:

```
const argon = require('argon2');


exports.seed = function (knex) {
  return knex('users').del()
    .then(function () {

      const password_hash = async (password) => {
        let hash = await argon.hash(password);
        console.log(hash); // this works
        return hash; // this does not
      }

      return knex('users').insert([
        { username: 'John Doe', email: 'johndoe@example.com', password_hash: password_hash('abc123') },
        { username: 'Jane Doe', email: 'janedoe@example.com', password_hash: password_hash('abc123') }
      ]);
    });
};
```

When I run my seed file, I can see the hashes being correctly console logged in the terminal, but when I check back in postgres, they both get saved as {}. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `password_hash` function returns a promise (via the `async` keyword). The insert is taking place without waiting for the hashes to be generated (even though you're seeing console output). What you want to do is take it step by step:

```
const users = [
  { username: 'John Do', email: 'johndoe@example.com', password: 'abc123' }
]
for (let user of users) {
  user.password_hash = await password_hash(user.password)
}

// Write the users to the db, but omit the plaintext `password` property
return knex('users').insert(users.map(({ password, ...rest }) => rest)
```

Your containing function will need to be declared `async`.